# How to get straight lines in an area chart in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, charts, line, area

I'm currently making an area chart on Excel but one of the lines isn't straight, as it's going diagonally upwards to the data point. Is there any way I can change this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2ytI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: =SERIES('2-dose'!$C$1,'2-dose'!$A$2:$A$53,'2-dose'!$C$2:$C$31,2)